# reading REALLY complex XML (up to 10 level)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

First off, sorry for my English, it's not my first language. So basically I'm developing a web application for our e-commerce company. I'm using Amazon API to get data. And these are in XML files.. I have never really worked with XML before, so I've been trying to learn but everything I found on the internet is for basic xml documents. Like 2-3 level deep and can be read easily by using simple foreach. I have tried to use foreach for this kind of document and I got lost in the code. I want to create an instance of a class by using this data. This example has only one product(product tag) and 10 offers(LowestOfferListings tag) for this product.

What should I use in my code to read every element and create instances?

I'm using **C#**

One response (GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse) can have up to 20 result (GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse)

a product (Product) may or may NOT have an offer (LowestOfferListings) but it has (Identifiers) for sure.

P.S. Closing tag for `GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse`does not show up in the codeblock below. I have no idea why. But there is a closing tag at the end

Here is a basic response using amazon API;

```
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult ASIN="ASIN_VALUE" status="Success">
    <AllOfferListingsConsidered>False</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
    <Product>
        <Identifiers>
            <MarketplaceASIN>
                <MarketplaceId>MARKETPLACE_ID_VALUE</MarketplaceId>
                <ASIN>ASIN_VALUE</ASIN>
            </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <LowestOfferListings>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>Unknown</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>3-7 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>80-89%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>2</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>190758</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>30.74</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>30.74</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>226962</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>31.50</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>31.50</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>Unknown</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>90-94%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>3</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>827887</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>31.68</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>31.68</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>False</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>3-7 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>9606</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>34.53</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>30.54</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>3.99</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>Unknown</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>80-89%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>2</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>457149</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>40.04</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>36.05</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>3.99</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>Unknown</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>473643</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>40.05</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>40.05</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>90-94%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>2</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>127</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>41.99</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>38.00</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>3.99</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>Unknown</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>3-7 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>1141</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>42.38</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>38.39</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>3.99</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>359758</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>43.09</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>43.09</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>Unknown</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>5876</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>46.18</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>46.18</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>Unknown</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
        </LowestOfferListings>
    </Product>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

I going to try to give you the complete answer.  There are many ways of parsing xml.  The best method depends on a lot of factors including number of tags in the xml file.  You have a standard xml response from amazon that contains lots of tags.  In this case writing a custom parse doesn't make a lot of sense.

So best method in this case is to use existing info from amazon.  So see amazon webpages

1) Documentation for response
https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN.html

2) Schema

http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/ProductsAPI_Response.xsd

Since there is an existing schema for response there are tools that will take the schema and create c# classes.  One you have the classes you can use xml serialization/de-serialization to read/write xml data.

MSDN has a tool see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Here is sample code I wrote to serialize and de-serialize xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLSerialize
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppConfig config = new AppConfig();
            config.Charts = new List<ChartGeneric>();
            Pie newPie = new Pie();
            config.Charts.Add(newPie);
            newPie.Attribute3 = "abc";

            StackedBar newStack = new StackedBar();
            config.Charts.Add(newStack);
            newStack.Attribute1 = "ghi";
            newStack.Attribute2 = "jkl";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppConfig));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, config);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();


            GetConfig(FILENAME);
        }
        public static AppConfig GetConfig(String filepath)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppConfig));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filepath);
            AppConfig configData = (AppConfig)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            return configData;
        }
    }
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("Configuration")]
    public class AppConfig
    {

        [XmlArray("Charts")]
        public List<ChartGeneric> Charts;

        [XmlElement("AnotherElement", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public XmlElement[] AnotherElement { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OneElement", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public XmlElement[] OneElement { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Pie))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(StackedBar))]
    [Serializable]
    public class ChartGeneric
    {
        public string Attribute1 { get; set; }

        public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Pie")]
    public class Pie : ChartGeneric
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Attribute3 { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "StackedBar")]
    public class StackedBar : ChartGeneric
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Attribute4 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Here is simplified solution for actual xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication64
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse));
            GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse response = (GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse", Namespace = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01")]
    public class GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult")]
        public List<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult> getLowestOfferListingsForASINResult { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult", Namespace = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01")]
    public class GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ASIN")]
        public string ASIN { get; set;}
        [XmlAttribute("status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AllOfferListingsConsidered")]
        public string AllOfferListingsConsidered { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Product")]
        public Product product { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product", Namespace = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01")]
    public class  Product
    {
        [XmlElement("Identifiers")]
        public Identifiers identifiers { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Identifiers", Namespace = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01")]
    public class Identifiers
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks clean. Thanks for your answer. I will look into serialization / de-serialization.

So basically, what I need to do is creating classes by using given scheme by amazon and serialize xml data into these classes, right?

Comment: Yes using the msdn tool.  You may need to add the three tags (first 3 in response) that are not in the schema as classes in the code.

Comment: I've been trying to get some results for hours. XML is really complicated. I created the class using xsd giving by amazon. I'm trying to deserialize but console window keep saying {
`“<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse xmlns=''> was not expected.”}`

There are some solutions for this, I've tried every one of them. This is just so frustrating

Comment: I updated code for first few tags manually to show example of working code.  The namespace issue is common with xml serialization.

Comment: I just reread your request and realized you needed an array so modified code changing : List<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult> getLowestOfferListingsForASINResult { get; set; }

Comment: I forgot to update last night, but as for now everything is working. That .xsd file worked like a charm. visual studio generated necessary classes. 

For the 'root' problem; I just needed to specify root tag just before deserializing. 

I'm just glad I'm done with dealing xml. thanks for your help jdweng, if you did not answer it might have took days..

Comment: I used List<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult> for some reason before reading your post here, I changed to code and did not use List this time. it didnt work. I dont understand why do I need a List for this. there is going to be only 1 GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult class in every XML response. I am only using className.ElementAt(0) instance for every response

Comment: From reading the description of the command at Amazon it appears that you do not need a List.   I'm not sure if you are using for the first 3 classes the code I posted or the one you  go from the tool.

Comment: The answer depends on the items in the square brackets above the classes and properties what will how to handle arrays.  When ARRAY appears in square brackets the serialize put in an extra tag layer. The best way of seeing this is if you have a  class filled with data serialize the classes to xml and save results.  So create two copies of your code in different namespaces.  One the reads with working code.  And one with changes that does not work that writes.